# Creating a reference to "this" in the only existing constructor of a class

Tags: java, constructor, singleton, this, keyword

A friend of mine showed me this as his implementation of the singleton pattern. It seems to work fine, from what I've tested so far. I cannot tell why, but referencing "this" as seen below, just seems like bad practice to me.

Is this usage of "this" in the constructor legitimate?

```java
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton unique = null;

    private Singleton() { unique = this; }

    public static Singleton instance() {
        if (unique == null)
            new Singleton();
        return unique;
    }
}
```

Is there even a significant difference, compared to doing it the usual way:

```java
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton unique = null;

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton instance() {
        if (unique == null)
            unique = new Singleton();
        return unique;
    }
}
```

I have not been able to find any reasonable answers to my questions.

So, thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend first one: it's a bit trickier to read (testing in one method; assignment in constructor); and it can end in problems if the class is extended. Significant: assignment before (all) constructors are done (*constructed* example: subclass constructor throws an exception, but assignment to `unique` is already done)

Comment: Neither are *thread-safe*. In any case (mutable) singletons are bad practice. If you want a constant, just write `static final MyConstant constant = new MyConstant();`.

Comment: Both implementatons have the same error - in some rare cases (race conditions) two or more "singleton" objects can be instatiated. See this article: [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) or this article: [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to learn how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this usage of "this" in the constructor legitimate?

It would work, but unreasonable and barely readable. It feels more like a code smell.

> Is there even a significant difference, compared to doing it the usual way?

Readability and maintainability should always be considered. It'll be harder to mock and/or use this singleton cause its implementation kind of *unique*.

Also, as pointed out in the comments. None of the examples are thread-safe. Means this is not a *true* singleton.

If you want a thread-safe singleton with lazy initialization, I'd suggest to implement it as follows:

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton unique = null;

private Singleton() {
}

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if (unique == null) {
        unique = new Singleton();
    }
    return unique;
}
}
```

You can enhance it by introducing Double check locking:

```
public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if (unique == null) {
        synchronized (Singleton.class) {
            if (unique == null) {  
                unique = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

---

**Additional Info**

There are multiple ways of implementing Singleton pattern:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-singleton-design-pattern-practices-examples/